# Can negative integers be relatively prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

We know that if $\gcd(a,b)$ is equal to $1,$ then they are relatively prime.

However, I have seen all pairs $(a,b)$ as positive integers. My question is can any pair $(a,b)$ of negative integers be relatively prime?

For example, are $(-1,-1)$ and $(-18,-5)$ relatively prime?

Comment: Yes and yes and yes.

Comment: Well, it depends on exactly what you mean.  I expect that any mathematician would define $\gcd(a,b)$ to be the greatest integer $d$ which divides both $a$ and $b$, in which case $a, b$ could certainly be negative.  But many standard software systems require positivity.  I just checked, and Wolfram seems to have no problem with negative arguments, but Excel reported an error.

Comment: If the gcd is equal to 1, not zero. The gcd is uniquely determined modulo units in the underlying ring, here ring of integers and the units there are +1 and -1.

Comment: @lulu  thanks sir, your answer is what i want to ask

Comment: For those who are answering, what about pairs like $(+a,-a)$? Does it matter if $a=1$, or $a$ is a prime number, or $a$ is a composite number?

Comment: @DreiCleaner it does not matter ,but it is obvious that except for 1,1 or -1,-1 it would not be relatively prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two integers $a$ and $b,$ we can obtain $\gcd(a, b) = d$ by running the Euclidean Algorithm. Explicitly, there exist integers $q_0$ and $r_0$ such that $a = bq_0 + r_0$ and $0 \leq r_0 \leq |b| - 1.$ Given that $r_0$ is nonzero, there exist integers $q_1$ and $r_1$ such that $b = r_0 q_1 + r_1$ and $0 \leq r_1 \leq r_0 - 1.$ Continuing in this way, there exists an integer $k$ such that $r_k \geq 1$ and $r_{k + 1} = 0$ by the Well-Ordering Principle. One can prove that $r_k = \gcd(a, b).$

Consequently, the greatest common divisor can be defined for any pair of integers $(a, b)$ regardless of their respective signs. We say that two integers $(a, b)$ are relatively prime whenever $\gcd(a, b) = 1,$ so again, this does not depend on the sign of $a$ and $b.$

Answer (score 3):

We may define relatively prime integers as follows.

Two integers are relatively prime if they do not have any common prime factors.

For example $5$ and $-12$ are relatively prime because the only  prime factor of $5$  is $5$ which is not a facotor of $-12$ whose prime factors are $2$ and $3$.